# Need a Best Video Player For My Video Hosting Site

Tags: files

I am creating a video sharing and hosting site on drupal but I am having difficulties in finding a good video player which can play almost all files. I have used media element but that is playing some mp4 files and some are not being played.

Secondly I want the video player to generate thumbnails by itself.

Comment: "Best" is hardly a constructive question. It'll vary from person to person. Ask how to solve specific problems and it'll be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

check that : [jw_player](https://drupal.org/project/jw_player).

For thumnbails you can use that : [DailyMotion](https://drupal.org/project/media_dailymotion), [Youtube](https://drupal.org/project/media_youtube).
its very simple to use it.